# What is the difference between constant and uniform acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology

What is the difference between constant and uniform acceleration ?

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference ?

Comment: English words typically have many meanings.  I can think of at least three different things that might reasonably called "uniform acceleration", just  as I can ghink of at least three different things thaf might be called "bugs".  Without contect there is no way to answer this.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Don't make the entire body of your question **bold**. Don't include superfluous greetings like "Hi! thank you for your time and patience." Don't include superfluous end matter like: "It would be really nice of you if you would answer this."

Comment: You might also want to consider changing your username, just for privacy reasons, since it currently appears to be your full name (tho I'm not sure if it really is).

Comment: The same question (and answer) would apply to velocity. You can find that here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/492797/what-is-the-difference-between-uniform-velocity-and-constant-velocity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between uniform velocity and constant velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/492797/what-is-the-difference-between-uniform-velocity-and-constant-velocity)

Answer (score 2):

They're the same thing. Uniform acceleration means constant acceleration :)

Comment: If a rigid rod is accelerated in such a way that at every moment, the acceleration vectors at the two ends of the rod are identical, I am entirely likely to call that acceleration "uniform" even if it is not  constant.  What words mean depends on who is using them, and in what context.

Comment: In that case the acceleration will uniform regarding the spatial coordinate and indeed it will also be constant w.r.t. that spatial coordinate.

Comment: Yes, it would be constant with respect to the spatial coordinate, but I personally would never call that "constant acceleration".  So depending on the speaker and the context, "uniform acceleration" and "constant acceleration" might or might not mean the same thing.

Comment: StiftungWarentest... what are you testing?

Comment: @WillO , in your example you're simply creating an ambiguity by introducing a new dimension, but that doesn't change what I mean. So let me clarify: if your acceleration a depends on a variable x, then " a is uniform in x" means "a is constant in x".

Comment: @hft rods apparently

Comment: @StiftungWarentest so “if your acceleration depends on a variable x” then “a is uniform” means it doesn’t depend on x because it is constant?